# How to deserialize { "result" : [ true, [1,2] ] } in .NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I tried to deserialize this JSON API Result but I have some problem with type.
In documentation this writes that this is a Python Tuple with another Tuple inside, i.e. `tuple(status, tuple(Imp, Vmp))`, but for `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` from Newtonsoft.json result is a list. Have someone idea what is the right type of `[true,[1,2]]` for deserialize using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`?

I tried types like: `Tuple<bool, Tuple<int,int>>`, `List<(bool, List<int>)>`, `(bool, List<int>)` and some another combination all without success.

Here's the JSON:

```
{  
   "result":[  
      true,
      [  
         1,
         2
      ]
   ]
}
```

Comment: try deserializing as `jtoken`

Answer (score 4):

Since `result` is an array of different types, define the following class:

```
public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "result")]
    public object[] Results { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can iterate over `Results[]`. I tested it with your sample and

- `Results[0]` will be `System.Boolean`
- `Results[1]` will be `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray`

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange layout, but JSON is known for them.

Unfortunately the nearest I can get to a POCO for this in c# is:

```
public struct Record
{
    public object[] result;
}
```

It kind of works, but it's ugly.  You can't use the results array directly, you end up having to use reflection to figure out what things are, and the nested array turns out as `JArray` (using Newtonsoft.Json).

If you're determined you can use a combination of `JsonArrayAttribute` and a custom `JsonConverter<T>` implementation.  As long as the format is consistent this works OK, otherwise it gets a bit tricky.  I can give you some code to try if you like.